# Haskell recursive function add to the end of a list

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a recursive Haskell function that takes a number n and generates a list that is n long of squared numbers from 1 up.

The code works but instead of the list for n=3 being [9,4,1] I want it to be [1,4,9].

```
sqNList :: Int -> [Int]
sqNList 0  = []
sqNList n  = n*n : sqNList (n-1)
```

I've tried swappig the : for a ++ but then the pattern matching doesn't work. I have only just started Haskell today so may be obvious

Comment: In that case you better use an *accumulator*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach is to implement `sqNList` in terms of a helper function that counts from 1 up to n.  That way you can just generate the list in the correct order in the first place.

```
sqNList :: Int -> [Int]
sqNList n = sqNListHelper 1 n

sqNListHelper :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
sqNListHelper current end = ...
```

There are a wide variety of more sophisticated approaches, but this is the easiest approach to debug/test interactively that also has you figuring out how to do everything yourself.

More sophisticated approaches can include list comprehensions or composing functions like `map` and `enumFromTo` to build up the logic from simpler pieces.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest approach that consumes probably the least amount of memory is to work with an *accumulator*: a parameter you pass and update through every recursive call.

Right now you use *n* as an accumulator, and decrement that, but we can decide to use an accumulator *i* instead that starts at `1`, and keeps *incrementing*:

```
helper :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
helper i n | i > n = []
           | otherwise = i*i : helper (i+1) n
```

Now we of course have to call it with `i = 1` ourselves, which is not ideal, but we can use a `where` clause that scopes the `helper` in the `sqNList`:

```
sqNList :: Int -> [Int]
sqNList n = helper 1 n
    where helper :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
          helper i n | i > n = []
                     | otherwise = i*i : helper (i+1) n
```

Now we can improve this a bit. For instanc there is no need to pass `n` through the `helper` calls, since it does not change, and is defined at the top level:

```
sqNList :: Int -> [Int]
sqNList n = helper 1
    where helper :: Int -> [Int]
          helper i | i > n = []
                   | otherwise = i*i : helper (i+1)
```

There is furthermore no need to only work with `Int`s: we can use any type `a` for which `Num a` and `Ord a`:

```
sqNList :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a]
sqNList n = helper 1
    where helper i | i > n = []
                   | otherwise = i*i : helper (i+1)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a more advanced technique, so you may want to just save this for future study.

---

Most recursive functions tend to use one of the same general forms of recursion, so knowing which higher-order function to use saves you the effort of reimplementing (possibly incorrectly) the recursion, and lets you focus on the work that is unique to your problem.

This particular type of recursion is captured by the `unfoldr` function, defined in `Data.List`, which lets you generate a (possibly infinite) list using a generator function and an initial seed value.

Its definition can be as simple as

```
unfoldr f x = case f x of
                    Nothing -> []
                    Just (new, next) = new : unfoldr f next
```

although the actual definition is slightly more complicated for efficiency.

Essentially, you just call the generator `f` on the seed value `x`. If the result is `Nothing`, return an empty list. Otherwise, build a list containing a result and the list produced by a recursive call with a new seed value.

Applying this to your problem, we produce a square and the next integer as long as the input is still small enough.

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)
sqNList n = unfoldr generator 1
            where generator x = if x > n then Nothing else Just (x*x, x+1)
```

So for a simple example like `sqNList 3`, it proceeds as follows:

1. Call `generator 1` and get back `Just (1, 2)`; the accumulator is now `[1]`.
2. Call `generator 2` and get back `Just (4, 3)`; the accumulator is now
   `[1,4]`.
3. Call `generator 3` and get back `Just (9, 4)`; the accumulator is now `[1,4,9]`.
4. Call `generator 4` and get back `Nothing`. Return the accumulator `[1,4,9]` as the result.

---

Note that you generate the infinite list of *all* squares simply by never returning `Nothing`:

```
allSquares = unfoldr (\x -> Just (x*x, x+1)) 1
```

Haskell, being lazy, only generates elements in the list as you need them, so you could also define `sqNList` by taking only the first `n` items of the infinite list.

```
sqNList n = take n (unfoldr (\x -> Just (x*x, x+1)) 1)
```

Comment: Do you have more info on these general forms of recursion? I often find myself writing recursive functions when I imagine it can be done with a fold or similar.

Comment: `map`, `filter`, `foldr` (and its cousin `foldl`) are probably the most common. `iterate` and `scanl` are fairly accessible as well. Bascially, any higher-order function that uses its function argument more than once qualifies. A good exercise is to try to implement them yourself. Eventually, you may want to google "recursion schemes" to learn more about the category-theory-inspired functions like catamorphisms (`foldr`), anamorphisms (`unfoldr`), and a whole host of other morphisms with Greek prefixes.